# Заменить строку при определённом значении

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как реализовать с помощью модуля re в питоне.

Есть строки:

```
1. Last login: Sun Mar 11 23:53:01 2018 from 192.168.88.26
2. etc
```

Нужно заменить всю строку на "X", если мы указываем слово для поиска - "Last"

В итоге:

```
1. X

2. etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "1. Last login: Sun Mar 11 23:53:01 2018 from 192.168.88.26";
if(a.find("Last") != -1):
   a = "X";
```

Comment: `if 'Last' in line:`

Comment: @jfs, + в карму)

Answer (score 1):

Если поставлена задача удалить только те строки, в которых есть слово `Last` как цельное слово, т.е. не `Lasted`, то понадобится регулярное выражение.

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/ogSUnC):

```
import re
stroka = """1. Last login: Sun Mar 11 23:53:01 2018 from 192.168.88.26
2. Lasted: 30 minutes
3. etc"""
slovo_dla_poiska = "Last"
regularka = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(slovo_dla_poiska))
rezultat = "\n".join(["X" if regularka.search(line) else line for line in stroka.split('\n')])
print(rezultat)
```

Результат:

```
X
2. Lasted: 30 minutes
3. etc
```

Регулярное выражение будет `\bLast\b`, оно найдёт только целые слова `Last`. Разбитые строки после проверки собираются с помощью метода `join`.